# How do Fyreslayers get food?

Tags: warhammer-fantasy, age-of-sigmar

I've been reading about factions in Age of Sigmar and I haven't found a good explanation for how Fyreslayers feed themselves. I understand it's a fantasy setting, but most of the other factions have some kind of plausible explanation for how they function. But it seems like all Fyreslayers do is either blacksmith or fight. Who is building their elaborate volcano themed fortresses or growing their food? Do they contract out to the Dispossessed or Kharadron Overlords?

Comment: A quick glance at [the wiki](https://ageofsigmar.fandom.com/wiki/Fyreslayers) suggests that they're largely a mercenary faction. One assumes that the answer is *"they buy their food from merchants who, in turn, buy it from farmers"*

Comment: That's the only reasonable conclusion I can see, though everything I've read in wikis and in the Soulbound RPG book seems to state they work explicitly for ur-gold. They're also treated as an entire faction (one the three presented factions within the Duardin), with holdings across the AoS universe, which seems almost more like the monastic fortresses of Japan and China.